# How can I append an index number to the auto-generated slug in Wagtail CMS

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am using [Wagtail CMS](https://wagtail.io/) for a project. I'm able to create entries and update them without issue.

I have moved the slug field from the Promote panel into my content panel. This is what my `models.py` looks like:

```
# models.py

...
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('slug'),
    ...
]

promote_panels = []
```

When creating a new entry, I am letting Wagtail populate the slug field. For example,

- Title: `Birthdays`
- Slug: `birthdays`

I'm able to enter all fields and successfully save the entry.

When I create a *new* entry with the same title, I am getting an error (when saving) that the slug must be unique.

```
ValidationError: {'slug': ['This slug is already in use']}
```

This makes sense that slugs must be unique - however, I would like to have Wagtail take care of that for me? I want to use the same page title of "Birthdays".

Is it possible to have Wagtail catch the exception and append `-1`, `-2` etc to the slug without throwing an error?

I am coming from [CraftCMS](https://craftcms.com/) and this is how the authoring experience worked...

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail has a [`find_available_slug`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/core/utils.py#L180-L209) method for this purpose, although it's undocumented and intended for Wagtail's own use so it may be removed without warning in a future version:

```
from wagtail.core.utils import find_available_slug

page.slug = find_available_slug('birthdays', parent_page)
```

Comment: this is a great suggestion! Works only if the page has been saved, otherwise there is no "parent" yet.

Comment: @PeterN No - you just have to pass it the parent page you _intend_ to save the new page under. (Which is something you must know, or else the question of finding an available slug doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found worked well. Please let me know as I'm sure there is likely a better, more efficient way.

```
# forms.py

from django.utils.text import slugify

...

class MyClass((WagtailAdminPageForm):
    cleaned_data = super(WagtailAdminPageForm, self).clean()

    # Ensure a unique slug for each entry
    if not self.instance.slug:
        cleaned_data['slug'] = slugify(f'{cleaned_data.get("title")} {Page.objects.filter(slug__startswith=cleaned_data.get("slug")).count()}')

    return cleaned_data
```

I am no-longer getting a validation error when saving an entry that has the same title. As a result, my slug(s) look like this:

Example:

- `birthdays`
- `birthdays-1`
- `birthdays-2`
- `birthdays-3` (and so on)

I am leaving the slug field in the admin panels so the author can change them accordingly.

Comment: This is a pretty obscure edge case, but this could fail if (for example) there were exactly 5 pages with a slug beginning with `birthdays`, and one of them was `birthdays-5`.